# rails referencing arrays created by the group_by function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, group-by

This code causes ActionController to return undefined method `name' for # How do I print the category name

```
<h2>Categories</h2>
<%= @categories.group_by(&:parent_id).each do |category| %>
 <%= category.name %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I mean, that the :parent_id is an attribute of Category model and @categories is a collection of ::ActiveRecord_Relation class. Let you try:

```
<h2>Categories</h2>
<%= @categories.group(:parent_id).each do |category| %>
 <%= category.name %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: that code plus the next line,causes the browser to render Collectibles [#<Category id: 1, name: "Collectibles", parent_id: 0, rating: nil, created_at: "2015-11-18 04:41:19", updated_at: "2015-11-18 04:41:19">]

Comment: I've supplemented the answer with full code. Does it looks like that one in your application? If so, how the proper result should be?

Comment: be careful, `group` and `group_by` are totally different, group works at the SQL level and group_by works in memory against the data in the array of models after they have already been fetched from the database

Comment: @house9 I know, but maybe I wrongly understood what this code is supposed to do.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `<%= debug @categories.group_by(&:parent_id) %>` so that you can inspect the data structure

I believe you want to pass two arguments to the each block, one for the parent and one for the categories associated with it

```
<h2>Categories</h2>
<% @categories.group_by(:parent).each do |parent, categories| %>
  <%= parent.name %>
  <ul>
    <% categories.sort_by(&:name).each do |category| %>
      <li><%= category.name %></li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
<% end %>
```

Above is based on my assumptions about your data model which could be totally incorrect?